# Shell script. if statement is not working

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have written a small shell scipt, but I cannot get my if statement to work.

I am running a while loop through a file (14380 lines and 134 columns), and I want to do some work on certain lines following the criteria  `number in column 4 > 6 and number in column 4 < 7`. The number in column 4 is a real number, and I know that the if-statement is only operating with integers. Is this my problem? I thought that the if-statement would read my number `get_lon` as a interger, ex. `get_lon=14.824` it would read it as `get_lon=14`. That would be okay with be.
After long time, it is not giving an error messages, but it do not filter data as I want. Right now all lines of the file are going through the test.

```
#!/bin/bash/sh
ulimit -s unlimited
datafile=$1

wfno=0
cat $datafile | while read line 

do        
    wfno=`expr $wfno + 1`  
    echo $wfno      

    get_lon=`awk '(NR=='$wfno'){print $4}' $datafile`
    echo $get_lon

    if test ["$get_lon" > "6" -a "$get_lon" < "7"] 
    then      
        awk '(NR=='$wfno'){for(i=7;i<=NF;i++){print i-7, $i;}}' $datafile > xy
        echo 'awk done '

        some more stuff...
    else
        echo "Line not valid"
    fi
done
```

Please, can anybody help?

Comment: Are you sure `/bin/bash/sh` is a shell?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-gt` (greater than) and `-lt` (lower than) to compare integers.

```
if ["$get_lon" -gt "6" -a "$get_lon" -lt "7"]
```

Comment: I have tryed this, but is getting an error: ` test: Illegal number: [93.31354450` 93.31... is `get_lon`

Comment: and if I remove `test` I get: `[93.31929210: not found`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space after `[`

Also the below works for me even with floats:

```
if [ "$count" -gt 1 -a "$count" -lt 2 ]|bc
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp.sh
#!/bin/sh

count=1.5
if [ "$count" -gt 1 -a "$count" -lt 2 ]|bc
then
echo "yes"
fi
> temp.sh
yes
>
```

Comment: I still get an error: `[: Illegal number: 93.33649580`. I have also tried to remove the `"`, but it does not make any differece.

Comment: try this:if [ "$get_lon" > 6 -a "$get_lon" < 7 ]

Comment: I get an error with your code as well: `temp.sh: 4: [: Illegal number: 1.5
yes` I do not get it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `expr` or `bc` instead when testing float numbers:

```
if expr "$get_lon" '>' 6 && expr "$get_lon" '<' 7; then
    ...
fi
```

Or

```
if [ "$(echo "$get_lon > 6" | bc)" = 1 -a "$(echo "$get_lon < 7" | bc)" = 1 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Using `expr` is more recommended as it doesn't need command substitution.